# how to play audio from parse.com in swift 2

Tags: swift2

i am trying to play audio from parse.com. I am getting the pffile but unable to play audio.

```
func testing() {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Attractions")
        query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: "hDyP0SwbAQ")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (result, error) -> Void in
            for obj in result! {
            let path = obj.objectForKey("attraction_file") as! PFFile

                self.playWithURL(path)
            }
        }
     }

    func playWithURL(url:PFFile) {
        do {

            let audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        }
    }
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: So what debugging have you done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found Answer.

earlier i was using AVAudioPlayer thats why i was getting the error.
now i am using AVPlayer and my code is working perfect.

var avAudioPlayer: AVPlayer? // declared in class

```
  func testing() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Attractions")
    query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: "hDyP0SwbAQ")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (result, error) -> Void in
        for obj in result! {
        let path = obj.objectForKey("SongFile") as! PFFile

        self.playWithURL(path)
        }
    }
 }
```

fun playWithUrl(url : String) {

```
 self.avAudioPlayer =  AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: url!)!)
 avAudioPlayer?.play()
```

}